# How do I create the same type of grey box with 'newtcolorbox' as 'newmdtheoremenv'?

Tags: color, tcolorbox, mdframed, ntheorem

I wanna convert into using `newtcolorbox` instead of `newmdtheoremv`. Here I have a simple, indented, grey box:

[image]

1. How do I achieve the same with `newtcolorbox`?
2. How would I be able to adjust between having a custom title and not having a title with the `\begin{greybox}` command? Some times I may want e.g. **Example**, ... as title and sometimes I may not want any title at all.
3. How would I do if I want the text to appear below the title and not directly after it?

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{ntheorem} % greybox COMMAND
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} % greybox COMMAND

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\newmdtheoremenv[
    backgroundcolor=gray!25,
    hidealllines=true,
    %leftline=false,
    %linewidth=10pt,
    %linecolor=white,
    leftmargin=15pt,
    rightmargin=15pt,
    innertopmargin=3pt,
    innerbottommargin=3pt,
    innerrightmargin=5pt,
    innerleftmargin=5pt,
    skipabove=12pt,
    skipbelow=20pt
]{greybox}{Example}

\begin{document}

Here is some text before to show the indentation.

\begin{greybox}
    Here is my grey box.
    
    With some text in it.
\end{greybox}

Here is some text after to show the indentation.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a new `tcolorbox` with `newtcolorbox` according to your style. Then derive several environments from it: with or without title, title on separate line, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybasecolorbox}[1][]{%
  colback=gray!25, colframe=gray!25,
  coltitle=black, fonttitle=\bfseries,
  sharp corners,
  width=(\linewidth-30pt),
  title=#1}

\newenvironment{mytitlebox}[1][]{%
  \centering
  \mybasecolorbox[#1]
  \itshape
}{%
  \endmybasecolorbox
}

\newenvironment{myinlinebox}[1][]{%
  \mytitlebox
  {\upshape\bfseries #1}%
}{%
  \endmybasecolorbox
}

\newenvironment{example}{%
  \mytitlebox[Example]
}{%
  \endmytitlebox
}

\newenvironment{example2}{%
  \myinlinebox[Example]
}{%
  \endmyinlinebox
}


\begin{document}

Here is some text before to show the indentation.

\begin{example}
  Here is my grey box.\par
  With some text in it.
\end{example}

\begin{example2}
  Here is my grey box.\par
  With some text in it.
\end{example2}

\begin{mytitlebox}
  Here is my grey box.\par
  With some text in it.
\end{mytitlebox}

\begin{mytitlebox}[Foobar]
  Here is my grey box.\par
  With some text in it.
\end{mytitlebox}

\begin{myinlinebox}[Foobar]
  Here is my grey box.\par
  With some text in it.
\end{myinlinebox}

Here is some text after to show the indentation.

\end{document}
```

[image]